# Secret scanner with a feature to create tasks in Jira

Tags: security, jira, devsecops

I have a question: is there any secret scanner with a feature to create tasks in Jira? Ideally, it would be great if all these findings could be included in a unified report to visualize everything at once.

**I need some reliable secret scanner with Jira integration**

Answer (score -1):

You could use something specifically designed as secret scanners like:

- Trufflehog
- Gitleaks

or you can use **bandit** for python or **Semgrep** for I think almost all languages.

These scanners you can use via **[whitespots.io](https://whitespots.io) security portal** and create tasks in Jira automatically

I think, that it would be more than enough to use this platform for reporting as well

Comment: Oh, thanks. I'll try it, sounds like what I need :)